# bash broken osx "[Process completed]"

Tags: linux, macos, bash, terminal

I had an error in a script, which ran 'brew unlink bash'. I then started getting: `Warning: bash already installed, it's just not linked`

I tried

```
brew update && brew install bash
sudo bash -c 'echo /usr/local/bin/bash >> /etc/shells'
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash `logname`
```

I tried to fix it by removing `/usr/local/bin/bash` from `/etc/shells` based on a different answer, but forgot to re-add it before exiting terminal. How I can't edit the file again because my terminal doesn't work at all:

```
login: /usr/local/bin/bash: No such file or directory

[Process completed]
```

After following instruction on how to fix terminal temporarily, I still have issue:

```
cchilders:~ 
$ sudo bash -c 'echo /usr/local/bin/bash >> /etc/shells'
Password:

cchilders:~ 
$ chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash `logname`
Changing shell for cchilders.
Password for cchilders: 
chsh: WARNING: shell '/usr/local/bin/bash' does not exist

cchilders:~ 
$ brew update && brew install bash
Updated 2 taps (caskroom/cask, caskroom/versions).
No changes to formulae.
Warning: bash-4.4.12 already installed, it's just not linked.
```

How can you restore terminals on osx? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Terminal, then choose Shell → New Command and run `/bin/bash`.

[image]

Comment: no idea how you did that. awesome :)

Comment: sorry i realized i still don't know how to fix it. i tried fixing it earlier before i had closed terminal

Comment: seems i made a goofy mistake, `bash-4.4.12 already installed, it's just not linked.` doesn't come up on google

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230967/homebrew-wont-link-git, I ran

```
brew doctor
# explained to link bash in the middle of output
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  bash

brew link bash

cchilders:~ 
$ echo $BASH_VERSION 
4.4.12(1)-release
```